# How to append a child to one of the elements in a variable by part of the class name and replace the parent?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS variable `var e` which is created by `document.createElement` method. I want to append a new element to an element inside the `e` which has `jackson` in its class name (full class name is `large button 1 jackson`). Also, how can I replace the `large button 1 jackson` element with the updated element afterwards? Would you suggest a solution?

Comment: What have you tried? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: @Utkanos, I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName, but how can I use  it for partial class name?

Comment: @Utkanos@hardy, I would appreciate it if you would give a hand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

```js
    // container element
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    // child element with class 'large button 1 jackson'
    e.innerHTML = '<div class="large button 1 jackson">some text</div>';
    // insert the container element
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    // new element
    var newElem = document.createElement('textarea');
    // find a element with jackson class (using .jackson as selector)
    var jackson = e.querySelector('.jackson');
    // insert new element
    jackson.appendChild(newElem);
```